# add custom language jelly bean---Laotian and Khmer language support

Tags: android, localization

I will add Laotian and Khmer language support in android 4.1(jelly bean).
  The process steps are as follows:

1.Modify languages_full.mk file lo_LA km_MM.

```
PRODUCT_LOCALES := en_US en_GB es_ES es_US fr_FR zh_CN zh_TW hi_IN it_IT pt_PT ru_RU lo_LA km_MM
```

2.Add Laotian, Khmer font file.

```
Font file is copied to the:/frameworks/base/data/fonts/
Laotian font file:Alice_3_Medium.ttf
Khmer font file:Klbachmool_Regular.ttf
```

3. Modify jb/frameworks/base/data/fonts/Android.mk

```
 font_src_files := \
Roboto-Regular.ttf \
Roboto-Bold.ttf \
Roboto-Italic.ttf \
Roboto-BoldItalic.ttf \
DroidSerif-Regular.ttf \
DroidSerif-Bold.ttf \
DroidSerif-Italic.ttf \
DroidSerif-BoldItalic.ttf \
DroidSansMono.ttf \
Clockopia.ttf \
AndroidClock.ttf \
AndroidClock_Highlight.ttf \
AndroidClock_Solid.ttf \
Alice_3_Medium.ttf \
Klbachmool_Regular.ttf
```

4. jb /frameworks/base/data/fonts/fonts.mk

```
4.1
PRODUCT_PACKAGES := \
DroidSansFallback.ttf \
Roboto-Regular.ttf \
Roboto-Bold.ttf \
Roboto-Italic.ttf \
Roboto-BoldItalic.ttf \
Roboto-Light.ttf \
Roboto-LightItalic.ttf \
RobotoCondensed-Regular.ttf \
RobotoCondensed-Bold.ttf \
RobotoCondensed-Italic.ttf \
RobotoCondensed-BoldItalic.ttf \
DroidNaskh-Regular.ttf \
DroidNaskh-Regular-SystemUI.ttf \
DroidSansDevanagari-Regular.ttf \
DroidSansHebrew-Regular.ttf \
DroidSansHebrew-Bold.ttf \
DroidSansThai.ttf \
DroidSerif-Regular.ttf \
DroidSerif-Bold.ttf \
DroidSerif-Italic.ttf \
DroidSerif-BoldItalic.ttf \
DroidSansMono.ttf \
DroidSansArmenian.ttf \
DroidSansGeorgian.ttf \
AndroidEmoji.ttf \
Clockopia.ttf \
AndroidClock.ttf \
AndroidClock_Highlight.ttf \
AndroidClock_Solid.ttf \
Alice_3_Medium.ttf \
Klbachmool_Regular.ttf
4.2
PRODUCT_COPY_FILES :=frameworks/base/data/fonts/system_fonts.xml:$(TARGET_COPY_OUT_SYSTEM)/etc/system_fonts.xml \    frameworks/base/data/fonts/fallback_fonts.xml:$(TARGET_COPY_OUT_SYSTEM)/etc/fallback_fonts.xml \
frameworks/base/data/fonts/fallback_fonts-km.xml:$(TARGET_COPY_OUT_SYSTEM)/etc/fallback_fonts-km.xml \
frameworks/base/data/fonts/fallback_fonts-lo.xml:$(TARGET_COPY_OUT_SYSTEM)/etc/fallback_fonts-lo.xml
```

5.  add file: 
  jb/frameworks/base/data/fonts/fallback_fonts-km.xml
  jb/frameworks/base/data/fonts/fallback_fonts-lo.xml

add frameworks\base\core\res\res\values-lo-rLA frameworks\base\core\res\res\values-km-rMM

last: system overall compile

run result:in Setting switch Laos and Khmer.Laos encoded unicode text can not be drawn on UI,
             Khmer encoded unicode text can not be drawn on UI.
  What is the reason?

Comment: Khmer language code should be: km_KH (not km_MM)

Answer (score 0):

People said Khmer Unicode rendering is already working fine in Jelly Bean (4.1), the missing is only font.

Here some link that might help you:

1. Method use in most Samsung devices for Jelly Bean to copy font to FlipFont: http://www.khmertype.org/2012/10/khmerapk-on-galaxy-note-ii-updated.html
2. Method to modify font system: http://nokorsoft.com/2012/07/android-jelly-bean-os-supports-khmer-unicode/

Hope it helps, It might be giving you another way for Khmer Unicode issue.